# why property of actual class in ObservableCollection is not found for DataGridTextcolumn but parent class property is?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I get:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'State'
>   property not found on 'object' ''PointNetObject' (HashCode=9270846)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=State; DataItem='PointNetObject'
>   (HashCode=9270846); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Text' (type 'String')

for one column. All the rows are added to table, but for each row i get the error. Two other columns are displayed just fine for each row. But not the State. Naturally the converter is never called.

Set-up described below.

I have an object:

```
public class PointNetObject : NetObject
{
    SwitchObjectState State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value; }
    }
}
```

which inherits class that has properties like Phase and Label

In ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<PointNetObject> SelectedSwitchItems { get; private set; }

public SelectedObjectsViewModel(SelectedObjects selectedObjects)
{
    SelectedSwitchItems = new ObservableCollection<PointNetObject>(GetSwitches());
}    


IEnumerable<PointNetObject> GetSwitches()
{
    foreach (var netObject in SelectedObjectsInstance.GetSelectedObjectItems(x => IsSwitch(x)))
    {
        yield return (PointNetObject) netObject;
    }
}
```

in View:

```
 <DataGrid Name="SelectedSwitchesGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSwitchItems}"
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource XpStrLabel}" Binding="{Binding Label}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource XpStrPhase}" Binding="{Binding Phase}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="{DynamicResource XpStrState}" Binding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource SwitchObjectStateToStringConverter}}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Comment: well your `SwitchObjectState State` property isn't `public`, which is, like, pretty important.

Comment: thanks, I'm an idiot

Comment: @Jonesopolis: Care to write as an asnwer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model:

```
public class PointNetObject : NetObject
{
    SwitchObjectState State
    {
       get { return _state; }
       set { _state = value; }
    }
}
```

You `State` property isn't declared as public.

Any properties you are binding to from the ViewModel to the View need to be public, or the View won't be able to see it.

Don't worry, we've all done it once.

Comment: You might want to make the State property public in your answer :/

Comment: Well i was pointing out that this is the problem area, maybe now it makes more sense

Comment: It's weird.  Normally, an answer contains a fixed version of OP's code, not the exact same code with a description of why it's wrong.  Anyhow, having given my unwanted opinion, I take my leave.  Good day to you, sir.

Comment: thanks! usually the classes I have in UI are made by me. this class with State was old and the property getter privacy was wrong even though it's been in use for years.